# How to drag a polygon in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapping, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with multiple polygons. The polygons need to move/update on user click/drag. The functionality I want is the same as this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/

I want to make the polygon draggable like the point example on mousedown, being able to move it on the map, updating the x/y coordinates of the polygon nodes throughout the event, but keeping the geojson size intact throughout the drag.

The point tutorial on Mapbox works well, but I'm unsure how to make it work with polygons.

Comment: Looking for the same problem, Have you found any solution @N Altun

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 3):

@Toni BCN your version is working, you just need to make sure to hand the coordinates over in the right format (the amount of brackets gets confusing):

```
let north = coords.lat + 0.17;
let west = coords.lng - 0.32;
let south = coords.lat - 0.17;
let east = coords.lng + 0.32;

geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = [[
    [west, north],
    [west, south],
    [east, south],
    [east, north],
    [west, north]
 ]];

 map.getSource('pol').setData(geojson);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5ynupb3/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for providing a fiddle. This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. use `draw.selectionchange` to catch polygon selection / unselection. Remember the selected polygon (event `features` property, most likely it's `features[0]`, since the selected feature is on top) in a variable; if you want the exact type, for polygon it's `GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Polygon>`;
2. use `draw.render` - it corresponds in particular to a dragging: check - if the variable is not null - the required polygon info; you might need to additionally check the current draw mode (`simple_select` or `direct_select`) to exclude wrong triggering. Do whatever you need here;
3. use `draw.update`: if `action` is `move`, it's a polygon 'draw end' event (apparently you may use the remembered variable, but you also have event `features` property at your disposal). Do whatever you need here.

Comment: I will follow up on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @NAltun does alexander's answer work? If yes, have you an example?

Comment: @ToniBCN no example that I can publicly post, unfortunately. Are you experiencing the same issue?

Comment: @NAltun I've made a jsfiddle based on the example from mapbox drag a point https://jsfiddle.net/dt1xsqk3/4/ but it does not work